# Sveltekit newly created cookie is not showing in the hook's handle function

Tags: cookies, svelte, sveltekit

### Summary

Once *set-cookie* header is sent in a response it takes another request before the cookie is visible in `handle()` function in the `hooks.ts` file.

### Example

1. User POSTs username & password to the login endpoint;
2. Enpoint responds with set *access_token* cookie header;
3. User should be redirected to a protected page. (**FAILS**)

> It fails because auth guard checks if the cookie exists, but it can't be seen from a code side at this point, only in the browser end.

4. *Refresh the page*
5. User is now able to be redirected to a protected page.

### [Minimal reproduction](https://github.com/rudgalvis/MR-svelte-cookie)

It has dummy login/logout functionality & protected user profile. There are also server side console logs which shows that cookie *lags* to be recognised in a hook.

Comment: I have a very similar example running flawlessly. The only difference i could find on first sight is that i am returning a `status: 302` instead of 200 when authenticating inside your login.ts file. Could you please try that as well? If it doesn`t work, please let me know and ill run your code on my side to troubleshoot

Comment: Hi, Did you found any solution for this? I've used `status: 302` but I am still facing this issue.

Comment: Hi, Blaze, status 302 did it for me.

Comment: Yup, 302 worked for me as well. Blaze, I'd try to double check if `contentType: "application/json"` header is set on the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your server returns the HTTP status code 200 which does not redirect the Client after the Login. The browser assumes it is already at its final destination due to the status code.

In this case, best practice is to use the status code 302: [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj679OLt_z0AhWGSvEDHQqAARwQFnoECBAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHTTP_302&usg=AOvVaw34e2rCIRjn3iCkXq7HTMSS)

Modified /src/routes/auth/login.ts

```
import * as cookie from 'cookie';

export const post = (request) => {
    return {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            location: '/',
            'set-cookie': `${cookie.serialize('token', 'VALUE_OF_THE_COOKIE')}; path=/; HttpOnly`
        }
    }
};

export const del = (request) => {
    return {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            location: '/',
            'set-cookie': `${cookie.serialize('token', '')}; path=/; HttpOnly; maxAge: 0`
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do we know why setting the HTTP response status to 302 would affect whether or not the cookie is readable in `hooks.ts`? Those seem unrelated to each other