# Sveltekit newly created cookie is not showing in the hook's getSession() function

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, discord, sveltekit

## Summary

Hello everyone, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70403075/sveltekit-newly-created-cookie-is-not-showing-in-the-hooks-handle-function) topic, I'm experimenting issues with my newly created cookie. I'm implementing Oauth2 to authenticate with Discord account in my SvelteKit project.
The flow is as follows:

1. User clicks on `index.svelte` hyperlink which redirect to `/api/auth` endpoint in my app.
2. The `/api/auth` endpoint is managed by `auth.ts` which makes a request to Discord Authentification Endpoint using my ClientID, RedirectURI (/api/callback) and Scope identify
3. Discord redirects to my callback endpoint `/api/callback` with a code set in the url, that a retrive using `url.searchParams.get('code')`
4. Then my callback function redirect the user to my main `index.svelte` file by setting a cookie containing the code sent by discord, I coded it to create the cookie no matter if the code is correctly retrived or no so I would know if the problem was here
5. In my `index.svelte` file, I call the getSession in `hooks.ts` to retrieve the cookie value and console log it.

The attended behavior is that after my callback redirection, the cookie should appear on the main page and it's value printed to my console. Which is not the case.
Instead I have to refresh my `index.svelte` page to get the cookie.

The link code to access `/api/auth` endpoint from `index.svelte`:

```
<a rel="external" href="/api/auth">
    Connexion
</a>
```

All my redirections are set with a status code of 302.

### Reproduction

You can find all my files at pastebin.com by following [this](https://pastebin.com/QsKBFq8C) link.

Anyone got an idea ?